# Let $a,b$ be positive integers that are coprime, then $ac+1=bd$ for some positive integers $c,d$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that:

> Let $a,b$ be positive integers that are coprime, then $ac+1=bd$ for some positive integers $c,d$.

I know that by Bezout's identity, there exists integers $c',d'$ such that $ac'+bd'=1$. But how can I guarantee that I find some $c'<0$ and $d'>0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're not, switch $c'\mapsto c'-b$ and $d'\mapsto d'+a$.